# Ripple does not cover text

Tags: flutter

I figured I can draw ripple over an image by enclosing the image in `Ink(decoration: BoxDecoration(image: ...))`, but how can I do the same for Text?

This is supposed to be a card with an image on top and a title and some other information at the bottom:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    final post = _postModel.post;

    return Material(
      color: theme.colorScheme.background,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        splashColor: Colors.red,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              if (post.imageUri != null)

                // This image IS covered by the ripple (what I need)
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 5 / 3,
                  child: Ink(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                      image: DecorationImage(
                        image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/700'),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              // This must be underneath the ripple, but isn't.
              Text(post.title, style: theme.textTheme.headline5),

              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 5),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                height: 60,
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[

                    // This is also covered by the ripple
                    Ink(
                      height: 35,
                      width: 35,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image: NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/100'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 5),

                    // This must be underneath the ripple but isn't
                    Ink(
                      // decoration: Decoration,
                      child: Text(
                        post.author,
                        style: theme.textTheme.caption,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I press, the ripple covers both images as expected, however, I can't figure out how to make the ripple cover the text widgets as well. I tried wrapping the text in an `Ink` widget (the last one), but it doesn't work - the text is still displayed over the ripple.

Unpressed:
[image: Unpressed]

Pressed (the text is visible):
[image: Pressed]

Comment: Is this you complete code? I don't see `children` in `Column`, and also you have the entire `Container` in `InkWell`, so even with an empty `Container` the red ripple works on the entire screen for me.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Oh, sorry, I was reducing the code on the go while writing the post and made a mistake. I'll edit and paste the full code

Comment: For me the ripple covers everything, maybe I don't understand correctly your problem.

Comment: @PeterKoltai I updated the post to show what it looks like on my phone. Could that somehow be specific to the version of Flutter or the platform that I'm using?

Comment: I got it now, so it happens when you keep tapped and wait for the ripple to "propagate". I think this is intended behaviour as [documented here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Ink-class.html): `Ink splashes and highlights, as rendered by InkWell and InkResponse, draw on the actual underlying Material, under whatever widgets are drawn over the material (such as Text and Icons`

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yeah, you are right, but that's exactly what I'm trying to solve. It just looks bad when the ripple goes underneath the images and the text and I want it not to do that. So is it possible to do this the way I want?   Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, maybe not or only with some fighting with material design. Are you sure it is a problem? Normally users don't press so long so they won't see it anyway. But of course if it's problem for you, keep digging, good luck!

Comment: Well, I didn't expect it to be that complicated, especially since they provide the possibility to to this with an image.